# Passing generic pandas dataframe to django REST API

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-rest-framework

I am currently building a REST API with the django and djangorestframework libraries. I want to make a POST that accepts a JSON-ified version of a pandas dataframe, so that I can then call some other library function on the dataframe and return some output.

I know that if I know the table structure of the dataframe, there are nice libraries like [django-rest-pandas](https://github.com/wq/django-rest-pandas) that can serialize and return pandas dataframes as JSON, but I am not sure about how to accept them as parameters to a function.

My current thought was to pass the JSON as a string to a function-based view, and from there, extract and parse the JSON as a pandas dataframe. However, I don't know if this is the best way to do this. My biggest complication is that I don't know the structure of the dataframe beforehand, so I am not sure how to incorporate that into a model that perhaps some library is able to interpret (although I am still interested in a way to do this if I did know the structure).

Here is my code so far.

Sample POST request:

```
{
    "table": "{\"AAPL\":{\"1420156800000\":103.8639572404,\"1420416000000\":100.9379443592,\"1420502400000\":100.947444401,\"1420588800000\":102.3629506325,\"1420675200000\":106.2959679468},\"AMZN\":{\"1420156800000\":308.52,\"1420416000000\":302.19,\"1420502400000\":295.29,\"1420588800000\":298.42,\"1420675200000\":300.46},\"FB\":{\"1420156800000\":78.45,\"1420416000000\":77.19,\"1420502400000\":76.15,\"1420588800000\":76.15,\"1420675200000\":78.175},\"GOOG\":{\"1420156800000\":524.81,\"1420416000000\":513.87,\"1420502400000\":501.96,\"1420588800000\":501.1,\"1420675200000\":502.68},\"MSFT\":{\"1420156800000\":43.3443122802,\"1420416000000\":42.9410878182,\"1420502400000\":42.3153946875,\"1420588800000\":42.8530273035,\"1420675200000\":44.1136830927}}",
    "num_samples": 10
}
```

models.py:

```
class EFObject(models.Model):
    table = models.TextField()
    num_samples = models.IntegerField()
```

serializers.py:

```
class EFObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EFObject
        fields = ('table', 'num_samples')
```

views.py:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from lib.api.serializers import *
import lib.analytics.analytics as analytics
import json
import pandas as pd

@api_view(http_method_names=['POST'])
def find_ef(request):
    serializer = EFObjectSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid()
    output = serializer.validated_data['table']
    num_samples = serializer.validated_data['num_samples']
    table = pd.read_json(output) 
    result = analytics.find_ef(table, num_samples) # returns a dictionary
    return Response(result)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework import routers
from lib.api import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'ef', views.find_ef)
]
```

This works, but my question is what I should really be doing in the view.py file, as this doesn't seem like the best way to get a dataframe (and it's also a hassle to correctly escape the JSON string of the dataframe after calling `table.to_json()`). Any help would be appreciated.